# Making Spawn Eggs with Custom NBT work in Spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to make custom spawn eggs with custom nbt work in spawners?  I tried putting a spawn egg with a villager named "Villager" in a spawner but the spawner only spawns villagers with no names.  Any other ideas what I have to do?

Comment: Could you provide the command you used that didn't work?

Comment: I did /give @p villager_spawn_egg{EntityTag:{id:"minecraft:villager",CustomName:"\"Villager\"",CustomNameVisible:1}}, but when I put it in the spawner, only villagers would spawn without its NBT.  I can do setblock which works, but I need to do a way where you would just only use a spawn egg to do that

Comment: oh i misunderstood

Comment: I do believe the spawner ignores NBT data from the spawn egg and only focuses on the egg type. If possible, explaining why you need a spawn egg to work may help to bring more possible solutions to light.